# Не выводятся значения массива с помощью cout <<

Tags: c++

В чем ошибка? Почему цифры числа не записываются в массив и не выводятся потом?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k = 0, ch, a;
    int array[123];
    cin >> ch;

    while (ch > 0) {
        a = ch % 10;
        ch = ch / 10;

        array[k++] = a;
    }
    cout << array[k];
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выводиться 0? ну наверное потому, что нужно сделать правильный вывод

```
for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
    cout << array[j];
}
```

а не просто `cout << array[k];`

Comment: спасибо! А как можно сделать, чтобы он еще и вывел количество выведенных элементов?

Comment: вводите то один элемент. Может быть цифр? тогда это будет k

    cout << k << endl;

Answer (score 1):

- Почему вы решили что они не записываются?
- Вы выводите один элемент массива, причём после последнего заполненного, там мусор.
- Не хватает вывода символа конца строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int k = 0, ch, a;
  int array[123];
  cin >> ch;

  while ( ch > 0 )
  {
    a = ch % 10;
    ch = ch / 10;
    array[k++] = a;
  }
  for (int i=k-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    cout << array[i] ;
  }
  system( "PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```